# Using custom credentials with Stackdriver Logging API C# Client Library

Tags: c#, .net, logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'd like to use a `GoogleCredential` object (or similar) in order to create a Stackdriver logging client object (an instance of `LoggingServiceV2Client` class) using some custom credentials rather than the default application credentials.

I cannot see an appropriate overload of the `LoggingServiceV2Client.Create` method but the docstring for that method states:

> Synchronously creates a
>   Google.Cloud.Logging.V2.LoggingServiceV2Client, applying defaults for
>   all unspecified settings, and creating a channel connecting to the
>   given endpoint with application default credentials where necessary.
>   **See the example for how to use custom credentials**.

which suggests it's possible somehow?

I have been unable to find a custom credentials example in the documentation anywhere. The only examples I see (eg [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries)) read only the *default* application credentials from the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable which I'd prefer to avoid

Comment: Actually, did you following the example in this [Github article](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.Logging.V2/Google.Cloud.Logging.V2/LoggingServiceV2Client.cs)? `<code>
        using Google.Cloud.Logging.V2;
      
         When running on Google Cloud Platform this will use the project Compute Credential.
        Or set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the path of a JSON
        credential file to use that credential.
        LoggingServiceV2Client client = await LoggingServiceV2Client.CreateAsync();
     </code>`

Comment: @SunnyJ.Thanks for responding. That suggestion using the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable IS the default application credentials I was specifically trying to avoid. Other Google API client libs (GA and BigQuery API client libs for example) allow client construction with a `GoogleCredential` object which can be created in a number of ways depending on the authentication scenario. It's odd to me that this API wouldn't have similar functionality? And also the documentation string on the `LoggingServiceV2Client.Create()` method seems to imply such a mechanism exists somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to use a custom credentials. Feel free to submit this as a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187158&template=1163028) through the Google Issue Tracker. You may also try using [service account](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/setup) instead.

Comment: @SunnyJ. Thanks for comming back to me. I will add a feauture request - is it also worth reporting an issue in that the docstring is misleading at best and arguably flatly wrong? (Thanks for the suggestion on the service account, I know it's possible to use those as the default app creds)

Comment: Yes, is worth reporting first as an "issue" for clarification, at the same time requesting that is upgraded to Feature Request if determined as not possible with Custom credentials.  Also, note: `the Issue link is a PUBLIC issue tracker, and as such, anybody can read the information in the report you file, hence, ensure to redact any information you consider personal or sensitive
before submitting the issue`.

Comment: The example is in [this documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Logging.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Logging.V2.LoggingServiceV2Client.html#Google_Cloud_Logging_V2_LoggingServiceV2Client_Create_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_ServiceEndpoint_Google_Cloud_Logging_V2_LoggingServiceV2Settings_). (It's not as easy as we'd like to use non-default credentials, but there are some very fiddly dependency and future-proofing issues making it hard to provide anything cleaner right now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but far from obvious.

Add these two using statements to the top of your .cs:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Grpc.Auth;
```

Then instantiate the client like this:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath)
    .CreateScoped(LoggingServiceV2Client.DefaultScopes);
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(
    LoggingServiceV2Client.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(),
    credential.ToChannelCredentials());
var client = LoggingServiceV2Client.Create(channel);
```

Comment: You saved my day. Tried hours to get this working with Cloud Text-to-Speech. Setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS did not work, even working directly with GoogleCredential.FromFile() didnt't work. What did work was to use GoogleCredential.FromFile() AND var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(TextToSpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions didn't work for me using Google.Cloud.Logging.V2 - Version: 3.4.0, because of this line:

```
var client = LoggingServiceV2Client.Create(channel);
```

In version 3.4.0 there is no constructor that takes a channel as a parameter.

So I checked google documentation : [LoggingServiceV2Client Create()](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Logging.V2/latest/Google.Cloud.Logging.V2.LoggingServiceV2Client#Google_Cloud_Logging_V2_LoggingServiceV2Client_Create), and it has this small note:

> To specify custom credentials or other settings, use LoggingServiceV2ClientBuilder

So here is my working code using this approach:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath).CreateScoped(LoggingServiceV2Client.DefaultScopes);

var client = new LoggingServiceV2ClientBuilder { ChannelCredentials = credential.ToChannelCredentials() }.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I already apreciated to @Jeffrey Rennie. In my case, I am using *Cloud Text-to-Speech* and I had to use following code:

Usings:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1;
using Grpc.Auth;
```

Code:

```
// Setting up credentials
string jsonPath = @"D:\my-test-project-0078ca7c0f8c.json";
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath).CreateScoped(TextToSpeechClient.DefaultScopes);
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(TextToSpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());

// Instantiate a client
TextToSpeechClient client = TextToSpeechClient.Create(channel);

// Perform the Text-to-Speech request, passing the text input with the selected voice parameters and audio file type 
var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(new SynthesizeSpeechRequest
{
    Input = new SynthesisInput() { Text = "My test sentence" },
    Voice = new VoiceSelectionParams() { LanguageCode = "en-US", SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Male },
    AudioConfig = new AudioConfig { AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3 };
});
```

**Installed NuGet Packages**:
Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 -Pre
Google.Apis.Auth